# Fetch as Google returning "Partial" not "Complete"

Tags: google-search-console

When I fetch a URL of my website, it gives me "partial" indexing status. I want fetch as Google to show "complete" status.

[image: "Fetch as Google" problem]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Partial just means that there were resources that couldn't be loaded. You cropped the picture to remove the list of resources, but below your cropped screenshot should be a list of resources that Googlebot failed to access alongside reasons why.

[image]

Partial vs. Complete does not refer to the indexing status. You can still submit the page to Google if you do not mind that the resources are blocked, as with the case in my screenshot.